# How does Deviant Art keep their dynamic images vertically centered on IE6?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to build a IE6 compatible site with dynamic images, but I can't seem get images to vertically align on IE6, can anyone help? I've been looking at plenty of sites and no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deviant art forces it's container to `display: table` and then set `display: table-cell;vertical-align: middle;` on the image http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on IE6 when I do it myself, is it working for you?

Comment: The site I linked to does. And just firebugging deviantart, I see thats what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to manually set the margin-top property of the image to make it appear vertically centered. For example if you had a `<div>` that was 400px tall and a child `<img>` that was 300px tall, you would set the `<img>`'s `margin-top: 50;` ((400-300)/2). This assumes you know heights of course.